# Solving $3x - 40 \cdot 2 = x + 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What did I do wrong?

[image]

1. Start problem
2. got rid of the 2 on the left side by reversing the multiplication
3. simplified - got rid of the two on the left side and divided on the right to get 2.5
4. undoing the subtraction of 40 by adding 40 to both sides
5. simplified - got rid of the 40 on the left side and added 40 to 2.5 on the right.
6. Undoing the multiplication of 3 on the left side by dividing by 3 on both sides.
7. Simplifying - got rid of the 3 on the left, and divided on the right
8. undid addition of x on right side by subtracting x on both sides
9. simplified ------ confusion

Comment: Try subtracting $x$ from both sides first.

Comment: Sorry but try to improve your writing and especially the number 2 which is unreadable.

Comment: @Sami I can write better on paper, I did this digitally with a mouse. I thought it was good enough to where it was legible though.

Comment: You're joking - right?

Comment: considering that he commented every step it is completely readable to me. user3402545: Using TeX is still the usual way to write formulae in questions, consider using it in the next questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is in step 2. If you're going to divide either side of the equation by $2$, you have to divide the entire equation on both sides. You did:
$$3x-\dfrac{40 \times 2}{2} = x+\dfrac{5}{2}$$
However, this is incorrect. The correct way to carry this out would be:
$$\dfrac{3x - 40 \times 2}{2} = \dfrac{x+5}{2}$$
But that's not really the easiest way to solve this. Try subtracting $x$ from both sides first. That leaves us with:
$$2x-40 \times 2=5$$
Try to take it from here.

Comment: Quick question - Why would that leave us with 2x - 40 * 2 = 5? Why is it not 3x - 40 * 2 = 5?

Comment: @user3402545 Because if you want to subtract $x$ from one side of the equation, you have to subtract it from the other side as well so that the equality is maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I forget that x is really 1x  -------- x = 42.5

Answer (score 1):

You divided some but not **all** of each side of your equation in step 2.

The result of dividing by 2 in step 2 should be $(3x-40\cdot 2)/2 = (x+5)/2$ which is $(3/2)x-40 = x/2+5/2$ which is $1.5x-40=0.5x+2.5$.

The next mistake occurs in line 7 where you have $...=\frac{x+42.5}{3}$ and then on the next line you have $x+42.5/3$ where you should have $x/3+42.5/3$ (the 3 divides both $x$ and $42.5$).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't divide the x on the right by 2 and didn't treat the multiplication on the left appropriately

It should go more like this
$3x - 40 \cdot 2 = 3x - 80 = x + 5$

$2x-80=5$

$2x = 85$

$x = \frac{85}{2}$